# Cannot see Resource group in Azure portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-group

Spoiler: I am new to Azure and Azure Powershell.

I started to learn Azure and Azure Powershell and my current self-given excercise was to write a script, which checks if a specifig resource group exist in Azure. If this specific resource group does not exist, then create one. So I started to write this script:

```
# Exit on error
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Import module for Azure Rm
Import-Module AzureRM

# Connect with Azure
Connect-AzureRmAccount

# Define name of Resource group we want to create
$ResourceGroupTest = "ResourceGroupForStorageAccount"

# Check if ResourceGroup exists
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupTest -ErrorVariable $NotPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "Start to check if Resource group '$($ResourceGroupTest)' exists..."
if ($NotPresent) {
    Write-Host "Resource group with name '$($ResourceGroupTest)' does not exist."

    # Create resource group
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupTest -Location "West Europe" -Verbose
} else {
    Write-Host "Found Resource group with name '$($ResourceGroupTest)'."
}
```

Now, when I run this script, I get this sort of output:

```
Start to check if Resource group 'ResourceGroupForStorageAccount' exists...
Found Resource group with name 'ResourceGroupForStorageAccount'.
Account                      SubscriptionName               Tenant ...
-------                      ----------------               -------- ...
my.email@host.com            Some subscription              ...
```

But I cannot find this newly created resource group with name *ResourceGroupForStorageAccount* in the list of resource groups in the Azure RM portal.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Hi kristian, any updates on your issue? does the work for you?

Comment: @IvanYang After I read your answer the first time, I changed it in my script and rerun it but did not see any changes. Now, some days later, I tried it again, it worked and now I can see the resource group in my Azure Portal. So, thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's too weird if not see the resource group after a while after creating it, but it's too glad that it works:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `-ErrorVariable` is incorrect, please use `NotPresent` instead of `$NotPresent` for the parameter `-ErrorVariable`. If you use `-ErrorVariable $NotPresent`, then the `$NotPresent` is always null/false, so the create resource command never executes.

sample code like below:

```
#your other code here.

# Check if ResourceGroup exists
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupTest -ErrorVariable NotPresent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Write-Host "Start to check if Resource group '$($ResourceGroupTest)' exists..."
if ($NotPresent) {
    Write-Host "Resource group with name '$($ResourceGroupTest)' does not exist."

    # Create resource group
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupTest -Location "West Europe" -Verbose
} else {
    Write-Host "Found Resource group with name '$($ResourceGroupTest)'."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just to add to existing answer, this happens because powershell expands variable in your expressions `-ErrorVariable $NotPresent`. and because your variable doesnt exist it becomes: `-ErrorVariable`. So it doesnt create a variable called not present and your `if()` statement doesnt work as you expect it to.